# TSQL (2014) - Importing XML with accented and punctuation Characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xml

Using this solution from Forrest:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderID>334</OrderID>
        <AmountPaid currencyID="EUR">17.10</AmountPaid>
        <UserID>marc58</UserID>
        <ShippingAddress>
            <Name>Marc Juppé</Name>
            <Address>Rue  garçonneé III° arrondissement</Address>
            <City>Paris</City>
            <StateOrProvince></StateOrProvince>
            <Country>FR</Country>
            <Phone>333333333</Phone>
            <PostalCode>22222</PostalCode>
         </ShippingAddress>
         <ShippingCosts>4.50</ShippingCosts>
         <Items>
            <Item>
               <Details>
                    <ItemID>3664</ItemID>
                    <Store>47</Store>
                    <Title>MCPU DDA010</Title>
                    <SKU>mmx</SKU>
                </Details>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <Price currencyID="EUR">6.2</Price>
            </Item>
            <Item>
               <Details>
                    <ItemID>3665</ItemID>
                    <Store>45</Store>
                    <Title>MCPU DFZ42</Title>
                    <SKU>mmy</SKU>
                </Details>
                <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                <Price currencyID="EUR">3.2</Price>
            </Item>
        </Items>
    </Order>
</Orders>'

SELECT 
    x.value('./ItemID[1]','int') AS ItemID,
    x.value('./Store[1]','int') AS Store,
    x.value('./Title[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Title,
    x.value('./SKU[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS SKU,
    x.value('../Quantity[1]','int') AS Qty,
    x.value('../Price[1]','decimal(11,2)') AS Price,
    x.query('//OrderID[1]').value('.','int') AS OrderID,
    x.query('//AmountPaid[1]').value('.','decimal(11,2)') AS AmountPaid,
    x.query('//UserID[1]').value('.','nvarchar(100)') AS UserID,
    x.query('//ShippingCosts[1]').value('.','decimal(11,2)') AS ShippingCosts
FROM @XML.nodes('//Item/Details') i(x)
```

I receive an error like

> XML parsing: line 162, character 34, illegal xml character

when need to parse fields containing accented characters (àèòìùé) or °

I tried converting `é` int `&egrave;` but get this error:

> XML parsing: line 162, character 41, well formed check: undeclared entity

while if I convert to `&#232;` it works.

The problem is I cannot HTMLEncode the XML File since I expect it will convert also all the "<" and ">" of the XML Structure, and probably also something else.

Can suggest the best solution to HTMLEncode the XML before parsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML you have is invalid in UTF-8 encoding. The accented characters needs to be encoded. For instance `°` should be encoded as `Â°`.

Here is a shorter version that also fails.

```
declare @X xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>°';
select @X.value('text()[1]', 'nchar(1)');
```

> Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 39,
>   illegal xml character

Should be like this instead if you use UTF-8.

```
declare @X xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>Â°';
select @X.value('text()[1]', 'nchar(1)');
```

You need to trace the source of the data backwards to the producer to see where you end up with invalid XML.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot control the input.
I checked twice the source file and it is not encoded:
Since issues can occour only in 2-3 fields, which can be best solution?

Comment: @Joe It is not the query that fails for you it is the assignment to the XML variable. You can try to remove the XML declaration and prefix the string with `N` in the assignment to the XML variable. `set @XML = N'<Orders ... >`

Comment: the `N'<Orders...>` option tested already but does not solve the issue..
OK will remove the XML declaration, but I thought there was a "non-hacking solution"
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Joe, No there is no "non-hacking solution" when you want to parse invalid XML with a XML parser that validates the input.